what parts of a radicchio plant are edible
I have planted radicchio this year and got a couple of big heads. The heads are surounded by green leaves. I was wondering, are those green leaves edible? They are so many of those green leaves that it seems a waste not to eat them :)
Thanks!

Could you chop and saute to decide if it's tasty?

Yes, all parts of radicchio are edible, though it's usual to discard some lower, outer leaves because they're often damaged. Suggestions for use here https://www.westcoastseeds.com/blogs/wcs-academy/radicchio#:~:text=The%20outer%20leaves%20are%20perfectly,core%20that%20is%20most%20prized.
